# how to use group or bucket in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data is looking like :

[image: hospital data]

how to arrange and group the data by speciality.

I tried like this this but it is resulting diff. format.

```
var data = db.collection('hms').aggregate([
    { $match: { speciality: doctorSpeciality } },
    { $project: { doctor: 1, speciality: 1, meetting_hours: 1, hospital:1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$doctor_speciality",
            "speciality": {$push:"$speciality"},
            "doctor":{$push :"$doctorSpeciality"},
            "hospital":{$push : "$hospital_name" },
            "meetting_hours":{$push: "$meetting_hours"}
        }
    }
]);
data.toArray(function(err, doc){
    console.log("result :::" ,doc);
});
```

I wanted like this format :

```
0:[
   { doctor:Hussain,speciality:Physician,hospital:HMS,date:2018-2-1},
   { doctor:Hussain,speciality:Physician,hospital:HMS,date:2018-2-2}
 ],
1: [{doctor:Reza,speciality:Physician,hospital:HMS,date:2018-2-1}]
```

and so on.

I am using MongoClient driver.

Could someone help me or give me some hints ?

Comment: Please provide a complete document/s so we can help. For instance, you group by `"$doctor_speciality"` for your `_id` but then `$push` `"$doctorSpeciality"`, is that a typo?

Comment: oh! its my bad typo, it is doctor_speciality.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to adjust to push all values at once instead of pushing the fields one at a time.

Try

```
db.collection('hms').aggregate([
  {"$match":{"speciality":doctorSpeciality}},
  {"$project":{"doctor":1,"speciality":1,"meetting_hours":1,"hospital":1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$doctor_speciality",
    "data":{
      "$push":{
        "speciality":"$speciality",
        "doctor":"$doctor_speciality",
        "hospital":"$hospital_name",
        "meetting_hours":"$meetting_hours"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```